# Expo react native Facebook login crashes on iOS standalone app

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook, expo

Facebook login is crashing on iOS standalone app but working fine on local Expo. I have tried a lot of things from internet but nothing seems to be working.

My expo diagnostics.

```
  expo: ^42.0.0 => 42.0.1
  react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
  react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
  react-native: 0.63.4 => 0.63.4
  react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18
  react-navigation: ^4.4.3 => 4.4.4
  Expo Workflow: bare
```

Expo Facebook

"expo-facebook": "~11.3.1"

Below is the error I am getting.

```
FBSDKLog: *** <activateApp, FBSDKAppEvents> is not called on the main thread. This can lead to errors.
    
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I am also having this issue, no solution found as of yet.

Comment: @ryantk I solved the issue. I will post it as an answer. It may help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the following lines to Info.plist file.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto_medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto.ttf</string>
        <string>rubicon-icon-font.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>

    <key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fbapi20130214</string>
  <string>fbapi20130410</string>
  <string>fbapi20130702</string>
  <string>fbapi20131010</string>
  <string>fbapi20131219</string>
  <string>fbapi20140410</string>
  <string>fbapi20140116</string>
  <string>fbapi20150313</string>
  <string>fbapi20150629</string>
  <string>fbapi20160328</string>
  <string>fbauth</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>


    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>your facebookscheme id</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>your facebook id</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>Your facebook display name</string>
```